# How to specify a city to Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

Anyone knows how can I specify a city to calculate DST in Moment.js?

Because in Brazil some cities change the DST rule so I can't use the detault TimeZone to calculate it.

My work is get a Date and a city that the user select, and I need to calculte de UTC Date. I'm going to do for all countries, but in Brazil I know this issue, so I want to know if there is a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone) plugin.

For example:

```
moment.tz("2014-10-01 12:00:00", "America/Sao_Paulo").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

Or:

```
moment.tz("2014-10-01 12:00:00", "America/Sao_Paulo").toISOString()
```

Keep in mind that Brazil has multiple time zones.  It's invalid to ask for "the time in Brazil" - you have to know *where* in Brazil to get an accurate answer.  [This Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Brazil) describes Brazil's time zones in detail, and has a table that lists the corresponding TZ identifiers.

Also, make sure you supply a date and a time - not just a date.  Otherwise, the conversion to UTC is meaningless.

Comment: Matt, my problem is that de DST in Brazil change a lot. Same states from the same TZ in one year had DST in another not  :S

Comment: Which is exactly why you need to specify the correct time zone identifier.  Those difference are represented in the data.